# Remove lines that doesn't contains a string with Sumlimes

Tags: text, filter, sublimetext2, notepad++, text-editor

I have 6 huge text files, and i need to filter them by deleting all the lines that doesn't contains the string: `53=S`.

For 5 of them, i managed to filter the files with `notepad++` as follow:

```
Find --> Mark --> Bookmark Lines --> Mark All --> Search --> Bookmarks -- > Remove Unbookmarked Lines
```

However, the application collapsed for a specific file each time i tried it. I tried it in two PCs with the same result.

Anyone know how can i remove the irrelevant lines with `Sublimes` or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regular expression replace in notepad++.

Using notepad++, press ctrl+h or bring up the search>replace window.

In the 'find what' text box enter `^(?m)^(?:(?!53=S).)*$`

and leave the 'replace with' text box empty

Make sure the search mode is set to 'Regular Expression' and then hit 'Replace All'

This should remove any line that doesn'tcontain the string 53=S

Answer (score 0):

There is a notepad++ plugin called LineFilter (not LineFilter2), which provides a menu with entries like

- delete all lines containing the selection
- delete all lines not containig the selection

it opens a new tab with the result. That worked on large files. I liked it a lot.

The plugin is available from [Notepad++ Plugin Central](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugins_By_Category).

If you have grep available, then grep should do the trick, too.